# How to block access to LAN through Open VPN running in Docker?

Tags: debian, docker, openvpn, local-area-network

I'm running Open VPN server inside Docker on Debian 10. It works great.
The problem is the connected client now can access my devices on my local network. I would like to block all access to all VPN clients.

```
LAN: 192.168.66.0/24
OpenVPN Server IP: 192.168.66.200
Router: 192.168.66.1
OpenVPN network: 172.20.10.0/24
Docker container network: bridge
```

Used `iptables` on the host but I can still access devices on my LAN:

`iptables -A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP`